# Cumulative minimum and maximum by group

Tags: r, algorithm

I'm trying to calculate the range minimum of a dataframe in R. The dataframe looks like this:

```
+-----+--------------+-----------+------+------+
| Key | DaysToEvent  | PriceEUR  | Pmin | Pmax |
+-----+--------------+-----------+------+------+
| AAA | 120          |        50 |   50 |   50 |
| AAA | 110          |        40 |   40 |   50 |
| AAA | 100          |        60 |   40 |   60 |
| BBB | ...          |           |      |      |
+-----+--------------+-----------+------+------+
```

So the range minimum price (`Pmin`) holds the minimum price of that key, up to that point in time ( `DaysToEvent` ).

Here's my implementation:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  currentRecord <- data[i,]

  if(currentRecord$Key != currentKey) {
    # New key detected - reset pmin and pmax
    pmin <- 100000
    pmax <- 0
    currentKey <- currentRecord$Key
  }

  if(currentRecord$PriceEUR < pmin) {
    pmin <- currentRecord$PriceEUR
  }
  if(currentRecord$PriceEUR > pmax) {
    pmax <- currentRecord$PriceEUR
  }

  currentRecord$Pmin <- pmin
  currentRecord$Pmax <- pmax

  # This line seems to be killing my performance
  # but otherwise the data variable is not updated in
  # global space
  data[i,] <- currentRecord
}
```

This works - but is REALLY slow, only a couple per second. It works because I've sorted the data frame like so `data = data[order(data$Key, -data$DaysToEvent), ]`. Reason for doing this, is because I was hoping to get a Big-O of `nlog(n)` for the sorting and `n` on the for loop. So I thought I'd be flying through this data, but I'm not AT ALL - takes hours.

How can I make this faster?

The previous approach is from my colleague - here in pseudo:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    ...
    currentRecord$Pmin <- data[subset on the key[find the min value of the price 
                      where DaysToEvent > currentRecord$DaysToEvent]]
    ...
}
```

Also works - but I think the order of this functions is way higher. `n^2log(n)` if I'm correct and takes days. So I thought I was going to improve on that big time.

So I've [tried to get my head around](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/) on all kinds of `*apply`, `by` functions and of course that's what you really want to use.

However - if I use `by()` and then split on the key. Gets me pretty close. However, I cannot get around how I would get the range minimum / max.
I'm trying to think in functional paradigm but I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Original answer: dplyr]**

You can solve this problem by using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(Key) %>% 
  mutate(Pmin=cummin(PriceEUR),Pmax=cummax(PriceEUR))

#   Key DaysToEvent PriceEUR Pmin Pmax
# 1 AAA         120       50   50   50
# 2 AAA         110       40   40   50
# 3 AAA         100       60   40   60
# 4 BBB         100       50   50   50
```

where `d` is supposed to be your data set:

```
d <- data.frame(Key=c('AAA','AAA','AAA','BBB'),DaysToEvent = c(120,110,100,100),PriceEUR = c(50,40,60,50), Pmin = c(50,40,40,30), Pmax = c(50,50,60,70))
```

**[Update: data.table]**

Another approach is to use `data.table`, which has a quite spectacular performance:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(d)
DT[,c("Pmin","Pmax") := list(cummin(PriceEUR),cummax(PriceEUR)),by=Key]

DT
#    Key DaysToEvent PriceEUR Pmin Pmax
# 1: AAA         120       50   50   50
# 2: AAA         110       40   40   50
# 3: AAA         100       60   40   60
# 4: BBB         100       50   50   50
```

**[Update 2: base R]**

Here is another approach in the case that you'd like to use only base R for some reason:

```
d$Pmin <- unlist(lapply(split(d$PriceEUR,d$Key),cummin))
d$Pmax <- unlist(lapply(split(d$PriceEUR,d$Key),cummax))
```

Comment: Wow kudos for the 3 options! I'll check them out !